Realization of mutable and immutable objects in python
I have encountered difficulties in understanding the realization of immutable and mutable objects. As I understand it, when trying to change a mutable object, such as an array, the interpreter simply modifies some defined memory cells that this array occupies. And when you try to change an immutable object, a separate memory area with a new object is allocated. But why not just write the new object to the same memory area where the old one was? What are the advantages of placing a new object at a new address?

Why are python strings and tuples are made immutable?

immutability is good. there are entire languages -- indeed entire programming paradigms -- where everything is immutable

and I think you are over-complicating your definition, immutability simply means this: there are no public methods that mutate the object. That's it. The interpreter itself doesn't treat these objects in a special way. You can actually mutate immutable objects if you use internal implementation details (of course, you shouldn't do that). So, you cannot "try to change" and immutable object because there are no methods that do so.

@juanpa.arrivillaga I remember some early versions of Fortran that had a very bad bug - function parameters were always passed by reference.  So if you passed a constant into a function, the function could make an assignment and change the value of your constant!

Python deals in names and references, not really variables, which can also be confusing for users used to "declaring" variables
Some great reading about the topic

https://david.goodger.org/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#python-has-names
https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html (thanks @chepner!)

When you create a new object, you can give it a name, or not bother
"hello"      # object which is the string "hello"
a = "hello"  # the name `a` now refers to a string "hello"

a = b = "hello"  # `a` and `b` now both refer to "hello"
a = "world"      # `b` is still "hello", but `a` refers to "world"
c                # raises `NameError` as there is no `c`

You actually see this frequently for docstrings
def foo():
    """ I'm a docstring, so I don't have a simple name in the function..
        however, outside I can be found at `foo.__doc__` !
    """

It's a simplification, but when you create a list (or other similar container), it then has all the references to its internals as named indicies
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l[0]  # a
l[1]  # b
l[2]  # c

If you change those references, you change where the names inside refer, but existing references won't be affected!
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> x = l[1]
>>> l[1] = True
>>> l             # field 1 of l has been changed!
['a', True, 'c']
>>> x             # but the name x still refers to "b"
'b'

Deeper (if confusingly), you could make a list with a list, and then make a name to that index!
>>> l = [[]]
>>> x = l[0]
>>> x.append("test")
>>> l                 # both `l` and `x` refer to the inner list!
[['test']]
>>> x
['test']

As to whether some particular object is mutable or immutable, while a language feature, is frequently a convenience to do optimizations and assure hashes work - there are not many, so you just have to remember and experiment until you get a good understanding
>>> {set([1]): 2}  # a set can mutate, so dict can't use it as a key!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
>>> {frozenset([1]): 2}
{frozenset({1}): 2}

For more and generally as a great reference, check out the official datamodel docs https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html it gets right into immutability and discusses all basic builtin types!

The old object still exists when you create a new one. This memory is not free for the new object to be put there, and only when you bind a variable name to new address, will this space be freed for a new object to be put there.
Very simple code that demonstrates the issue (Note: it might not work as described, based on implementation details)
x = "foo"
a = x * 2
print(id(a)) # 2874144541504
a = x * 2
print(id(a)) # 2874144541552 
a = x * 2
print(id(a)) # 2874144541504

We can see that ids 1 and 3 are the same, but 2 is different. That's because when we do 2nd x * 2, memory at id 1 is not free yet. But, since we lose reference to the old value after assignment, it gets garbage collected and can be assigned again with 3rd assignment.

Do I understand correctly that a new object is created first, and only then does the identifier begin to refer to this object? Let's take an example where I don't even change an immutable object, but just assign a new value to an identifier. For example, a = "asd", and then a = "x". In this case, the interpreter will first create the 'x' object and only then delete the "asd" object?

Yes, that's correct. You might want to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Correct. It first creates "x" object. Then it assigns it to variable named a. Only then, Garbage Collector sees that object "asd" is not referenced by any variable, and can therefore be deleted (at some point in the future)

@Slaycapь the expression "x" creates a new object. The result of that expression is assigned to the identifier a, there is one less reference to whatever object the identifier was previously referencing, and if the reference count is 0, then the object is free to be garbage collected. In CPython, that happens immediately
